# my debug session in pycharm is not showing the 'lighting bolt' on a divide by zero exception

Tags: debugging, pycharm

i was trying to follow the Jet brains tutorial for debugging your first project... but when im in the debugger and step into a divide by zero... the debugger seems to ignore it! even though the console window shows it.  what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does the debugger show?

Comment: the debugger windows just 'go grey'. i can look in the console window and i see the exception has been thrown.

keep in mind. i was just trying to create the 'car' example in the jetbrains tutorial.  but when i create my own project and do a simple div/0 i can see the debugger working as expected.  so im wondering what am i doing in the car project that makes the debugger need a debugger :) !

Comment: If I understand your situation, I think the program is crashing and, therefore, halting the interpreter / debugger. I believe fatal errors pull you out of the debugger. To check this, add a breakpoint on the line before it crashes and then debug. It should stop on that line, showing you what to expect in the debugger.

Comment: yes. i set the breakpoint just before the divide by 0 statement and i can see the denominator will be 0. then when i continue... the console shows the exception but the debugger basically gets grayed out ..but i can rerun it by clicking on the green bug.
remember... all im doing is running the very example that jetbrains provides in their tutorial ... nothing fancy :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Does that get you where you need to be? Good luck w/ Pycharm & Python!

Comment: yeah... im way past that. thanks. im able to run the debugger on other scripts I wrote . its wierd that it failed on the very tutorial that jetbrains provides.   Rgsd!